# Idiomatic way to map a concept to a concrete type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Given a set of C++ concepts:

```
concept A = ...;
concept B = ...;
concept C = ...;
```

And a set of down-to-earth, non-template, types:

```
class ProcessA;
class ProcessB;
class ProcessC;
```

Is there an idiomatic way to write a meta-function `get_matching_type` such that:

```
std::is_same_v<get_matching_type<TypeThatSatisfiesA>, ProcessA>;
std::is_same_v<get_matching_type<TypeThatSatisfiesB>, ProcessB>;
std::is_same_v<get_matching_type<TypeThatSatisfiesC>, ProcessC>;
```

all holds ? Basically, how to map a C++ concept to a C++ type.

The only simple way I see are:
1/ Through imbrication of conditionals, e.g. something like:

```
 using get_matching_type = std::conditional_t<A<T>, ProcessA, 
                              std::conditional_t<B<T>, ProcessB, 
                                std::conditional_t<C<T>, ProcessC>
                              >
                            >;
```

but I would like to have a function that isn't going to make template instantiation depth go through the roof.

2/ Through specialization:

```
template<A T>
struct get_matching_type<T> { using type = ProcessA; };
template<B T>
struct get_matching_type<T> { using type = ProcessB; };
template<C T>
struct get_matching_type<T> { using type = ProcessC; };
```

but the boilerplate goes through the roof :)

Comment: Why do you need this? If your concept only matches ONE type, then why is it a concept?

Comment: No, my concept can match an arbitrary number of types. For instance: all structs with a { float value; } member. But for all the types that satisfy this (and which may come from codebases outside of mine), there is one actual operation that I can apply to it.

Answer (score 2):

"Pattern matching" can be done with overloads:

```
template <TypeThatSatisfiesA T> ProcessA helper(T*);
template <TypeThatSatisfiesB T> ProcessB helper(T*);
template <TypeThatSatisfiesC T> ProcessC helper(T*);

template <typename T>
using get_matching_type = decltype(helper(std::declval<T*>()));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/376Kos94P)

Answer (score 0):

A concept is nothing more than a glorified boolean function. You can evaluate a function given the arguments, but it is fundamentally impossible, given the function, to efficiently determine at which arguments it evaluates to `true`. The only way to do that is basically to enumerate all possible argument combinations and see what the function evaluates to at each combination.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction):

```
template<bool V, class T>
struct match : std::bool_constant<V> { using type = T; };

template<class T>
using get_matching_type = typename std::disjunction<
    match<A<T>, ProcessA>,
    match<B<T>, ProcessB>,
    match<C<T>, ProcessC>,
    std::false_type>::type;
```

This works because `std::disjunction` returns (by inheritance) the first of its parameters that has a true-valued `::value`; it need not be a direct instantiation of `std::bool_constant` but can hold other data.